# Why am I encountering a weird error when opening a form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

So I've got this form that has a map as a background and contains around 330 picturebox, At first it will open but after some attempts of opening it, it will show an error of: "InvalidOperationException was Unhandled: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Parameter is not valid."

Can someone please tell me why is it occuring? Is it because of the number of picbox inside it? and i am not quite sure of how the error is triggered, but opening other forms may cause it though it is not consistent.

[image]

[image]

So this is what's inside line 4682 of frmVirtualSiteMap.Designer.vb:

```
    Me.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch
```

Comment: See Exception.InnerException for details.

Comment: It only says "See general help...", something like that

Comment: I'm sorry, I've uploaded it.

Comment: You're still not looking at the inner exception, so you're just guessing what the original problem is. Don't guess; *look.* Click "View Detail...", then expand the InnerException. If there's another level of InnerException inside there, dig into that too. Once you get to the end of the line, you're looking at the exception that started it all, and now you know the exception type, the message, and perhaps most importantly, the call stack -- which will tell you the exact line of code that has the problem.

Comment: I already did, and it's as I stated in my edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just changed the BackgroundImageLayout of the form into None and it went good even though there's a rare occasion that all picturebox and the form will show only an "X" sign. I'm still not sure why it happened or what's causing it but I think I just need to resize the pictures to fit my form.